# How do you add a gzip MessageEncoding bindingElementExtension to existing WCF/WSDL application?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

I'm trying to drop the gzip compression message encoder from the [MS WCF samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx) pack into an existing WCF/WSDL application (that uses `basicHttpBinding`), but I'm having problems with the app config.

I added the GZipEncoder project from the sample to my solution (contains GZipMessageEncoderFactory, GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement and GZipMessageEncodingBindingElementImporter), then added the extension into `serviceModel/extensions` of Web.config (the full final web.config is at the bottom of my question):

```
<bindingElementExtensions>
  <add name="gzipMessageEncoding" type="Microsoft.Samples.GZipEncoder.GZipMessageEncodingElement, GZipEncoder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
</bindingElementExtensions>
```

..added `gzipMessageEncoding` to the `bindings/basicHttpBinding/binding` section:

```
<gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding" />
```

`gzipMessageEncoding` is not recognized by the parser, so I replaced the basicHttpBinding with a custom one in `serviceModel/bindings`:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="customBinding" closeTimeout="00:15:00" openTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00">
    <gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding"/>
    <httpTransport hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" manualAddressing="False" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
     authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="False" realm="" useDefaultWebProxy="True" transferMode="Buffered"/>
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

and to `serviceModel`:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="customBinding" />
</protocolMapping>
```

then named the customBinding in my endpoint:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="KiProjectsSyncServiceBehavior" name="KiProjectsSyncService">
  <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="KiProjectsSyncService" contract="IKiProjectsSyncService"/>
```

But I get the error when I browse to the service:

> The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/customBinding does not
>   have a configured binding named 'KiProjectsSyncService'. This is an
>   invalid value for bindingConfiguration.

I just want to attach gzip to basicHttp or some other simple text binding. The sample seems to do this, but I can't see where I diverged from its example. It would be great to understand this config, as this functionality will need to be adapted to all sorts of contexts in the future, and one of the reasons I decided against REST is the flexibility of this architecture.

FYIs: I want compression in both directions, and I believe turning compression on in IIS only compresses download. My application is two IIS server ASP applications communicating to each other. I transfer DataContract and MessageContract types over the interface (the latter for streaming files in both directions, although actually they're buffered as I'm using BasicHttp). It is all working well - just struggling to add compression. I have also altered the client web.config (bindingElementExtensions, endPoint bindingConfig and binding, policyImporters and customBinding), but am getting these issues just trying to browse to my .svc service, without involving the client.

Full web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="KiSuiteConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="gzipMessageEncoding" type="Microsoft.Samples.GZipEncoder.GZipMessageEncodingElement, GZipEncoder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="customBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="customBinding" closeTimeout="00:15:00" openTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00">
          <gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding"/>
          <httpTransport hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" manualAddressing="False" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                         authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="False" realm="" useDefaultWebProxy="True" transferMode="Buffered"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="KiProjectsSyncServiceBehavior" name="KiProjectsSyncService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="KiProjectsSyncService" contract="IKiProjectsSyncService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="KiProjectsSyncServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think I fixed it (working on client config now). In `endpoint`, the `bindingConfiguration` has to be the same as `binding`, ie, `customBinding`. Service now seems to appear in the browser but not yet connected with the client. Will post when I suss this out.

Answer (score 0):

All I had wrong was the `endpoint` `bindingConfiguration` must be set to the same value as the binding (in my case, `customBinding`), ie:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="KiProjectsSyncServiceBehavior" name="KiProjectsSyncService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinding" contract="Kimetrica.Sync.IKiProjectsSyncService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

I *imagine* that bindingConfiguration setting can be used to plug in new customizations to the WCF framework. Then in the client web.config I had to add the following:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="gzipMessageEncoding" type="Kimetrica.Sync.GZipEncoder.GZipMessageEncodingElement, GZipEncoder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="customBinding" closeTimeout="00:15:00" openTimeout="00:15:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00">
          <gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding" />
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" useDefaultWebProxy="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1062/WcfTestWebSite/KiProjectsSyncService.svc"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customBinding"
                contract="KiProjectsSyncServiceReference.IKiProjectsSyncService" name="KiProjectsSyncService" />
      <metadata>
        <policyImporters>
          <extension type="Microsoft.Samples.GZipEncoder.GZipMessageEncodingBindingElementImporter, GZipEncoder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
        </policyImporters>
      </metadata>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This successfully adds gzip compression and send DataContracts and MessageContracts incorporating FileStreams (including over the default 64kb limit), IIS ASP app to IIS ASP app.